# Enum.reduce to put strings into the right list

Tags: list, dictionary, enums, elixir, reduce

I have this function that splits a string into parts, and I need to place these parts into the right list within the `params` map.

```
parts = String.split(term_string, " ")

params = %{
  search_terms: [],
  wildcard_terms: [],
  minus_terms: [],
  room_terms: [],
  messages_to_terms: [],
  messages_from_terms: [],
  date_before_terms: [],
  date_after_terms: [],
  date_on_terms: [],
  date_during_terms: []
}

Enum.reduce(parts, params, fn p ->
  cond do
    String.ends_with?(p, "*") ->
      params[:wildcard_terms] = [p | params[:wildcard_terms]]

    true ->
      params[:search_terms] = [p | params[:search_terms]]
  end
end)
```

I'm getting `cannot invoke remote function Access.get/2 inside match` error right now and I'm not sure how to address the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you are not thinking in immutable terms. `params[:wildcard_terms] = [p | params[:wildcard_terms]]` does not do what you think it does. It does not update a value associated with a key inside your map `params` as you may be accustomed to from other languages like Ruby/Java/Python. That is why dogbert's solution advocates the use of `Map.update!`, which behind the scenes creates a new map with all the same values except for the one corresponding to the key specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a new map with the updated list inside in the reducing function. One way to do that is to use `Map.update!`:

```
Enum.reduce(parts, params, fn p ->
  cond do
    String.ends_with?(p, "*") ->
      Map.update!(params, :wildcard_terms, fn ps -> [p | ps] end)

    true ->
      Map.update!(params, :search_terms, fn ps -> [p | ps] end)
  end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the @Dogbert’s solution is surely perfectly robust, I would refactor this code a bit to make it more succinct:

```rb
Enum.reduce(parts, params, fn p ->
  key =
    if String.ends_with?(p, "*") do
      :wildcard_terms
    else
      :search_terms
    end

  Map.update!(params, key, fn ps -> [p | ps] end)
end)
```

or, if you prefer more verbose (and slow—see the valuable Dogbert’s comment below) but easy-to-read approach (based on matching the mapper argument):

```rb
parts
|> Enum.map(&String.reverse/1)
|> Enum.reduce(params, fn
     <<"*", _::binary>> = p -> 
       %{params | wildcard_terms: [p | params.wildcard_terms]}
     p ->
       %{params | search_terms: [p | params.search_terms]}
   end)
```

Comment: The second one will be unnecessarily slow though - `ends_with?` is O(1) while `String.reverse` will make a copy of the whole binary (O(n)).

Comment: @Dogbert yes, indeed, thanks. I have added a notice; I am not sure if this is better readable at all when `reverse` is required, but I wanted to preach/demonstrate the pattern-matching approach in general.